# Can I make use on templates when implementing different interfaces in the same way?

Tags: c++, templates, interface, virtual-functions

I have many interfaces for different listeners, the all look like this:

```
class ListenerA
{
public:
    virtual void
    onEventA(const EventA&) = 0;
};

class ListenerB
{
public:
    virtual void 
    onEventB(const EventB&) = 0;
};
```

When testing, I always end up just collecting those events in a `std::vector` for analyzing them afterwards in a specific test suite. Those event collectors all look the same like this one for example:

```
class EventACollector : public ListenerA
{
public:

    const auto&
    events() const
    {
        return m_events;
    }

private:

    void
    onEventA(const EventA& event) override
    {
        m_events.emplace_back(event);
    }

    std::vector<EventA> m_events;
};
```

Is there a way to template an EventTCollector, so that I do not have to write it every time? Given that the virtual function name does change for every listeners?

Comment: You can have a base `EventTCollector` and then extends it for each one your listener by only implementing `onEventX`, but you cannot have a `EventTCollector` templated that you could instantiate for the different listeners. If it's mostly for test purpose, maybe macros (or macros+template) would be the best way to do it.

Comment: Any reason they have to have different names, or can you use `onEvent`? A class can still implement multiple listeners because of overloading.

Comment: @parktomatomi I do not know what the reason was, some team decided to have those like that and I cannot change them now (unfortunately)

Comment: When naming is involved, there is still MACRO...

Comment: @Jarod42 may them be blessed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ does not have introspection, so you cannot find the `virtual` function in `ListenerA`. The other parts can go in a templated base class, but the override you'll need to define manually.

Modern C++ would use a `std::function<void(EventA)>` instead of a named interface, but that won't help you as a user of that old interface.

Comment: I suspected that, thanks for confirming. I think that if at least the listeners were having `virtual operator()(const Event)` instead of a virtual named function, I might have been able to template it.